# how to reshape 2d numpy array to 4d (without ValueError)

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, h5py

I have script that convert `.csv` file to `h5` (binary),
the .csv file columns contains: Image (as numpy array) and 3 more float numbers.

```
import os

import numpy as np
from pandas.io.parsers import read_csv
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
import h5py

FTRAIN = 'training.csv'
FTEST = 'test.csv'


def load(test=False, cols=None):
    """Loads data from FTEST if *test* is True, otherwise from FTRAIN.
    Pass a list of *cols* if you're only interested in a subset of the
    target columns.
    """
    fname = FTEST if test else FTRAIN
    df = read_csv(os.path.expanduser(fname))  # load pandas dataframe

    # The Image column has pixel values separated by space; convert
    # the values to numpy arrays:
    df['Image'] = df['Image'].apply(lambda im: np.fromstring(im, sep=' '))

    if cols:  # get a subset of columns
        df = df[list(cols) + ['Image']]

    print(df.count())  # prints the number of values for each column
    df = df.dropna()  # drop all rows that have missing values in them

    X = np.vstack(df['Image'].values) / 255.  # scale pixel values to [0, 1]
    X = X.astype(np.float32)

    if not test:  # only FTRAIN has any target columns
        y = df[df.columns[:-1]].values
        y = (y - 48) / 48  # scale target coordinates to [-1, 1]
        X, y = shuffle(X, y, random_state=42)  # shuffle train data
        y = y.astype(np.float32)
    else:
        y = None

    return X, y

def writeHdf5(t,data,label=None):
    with h5py.File(os.getcwd()+ '/'+t + '_data.h5', 'w') as f:
        f['data'] = data
        if label is not None:
            f['label'] = label
    with open(os.getcwd()+ '/'+t + '_data_list.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(os.getcwd()+ '/' +t + '_data.h5\n')


X, y = load()
X = X.reshape((X.shape[0],3,96,96))
sep = 1600
writeHdf5('train',X[0:sep],y[0:sep])
writeHdf5('val',X[sep:],y[sep:])

X,y= load(True)
X = X.reshape((X.shape[0],3,96,96))
writeHdf5('test',X,y)
```

when I want to reshape X from 2d to 4d:

```
 X = X.reshape((X.shape[0],3,256,256)
```

X shape: (10464, 2622) (2d - before the conversion)

it shows me the following error:

```
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

what am I doing wrong? thanks.

Comment: You are changing the size of the array. Reshape allows you to redistribute the elements, but the number of them must be the same (i.e. The size of X.shape[0] is 2622 elements, and you are trying to convert them to a 3x256x256=196608 element array)

Comment: @Jalo thank you. how can I reshape the array with ability to change the number of array elements?

Comment: That depends on how you want to create the new data in the array. You are creating new elements, thus you have to decide what are they going to contain. Some basic functions for adding rows and columns are [vstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) and [hstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html)